# How to associate an (AlarmManager) notification with an object it was associated with?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

So the title is very uninformative because this issue is hard to describe. Essentially, I have a series of Alarm objects each with an id, time, name, etc. and when I created the PendingIntent for the AlarmManager i tagged the PendingIntent with the id of the Alarm it was associated with, so I could delete the alarm later (if the user decided to delete it). But when the Alarm goes off, I have a class `AlarmReceiver.java` that extends `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and a method `onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)`

```
package org.rtsd.morningtalk;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Zig on 1/18/2016.
 */
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent){
        //Call the Text-to-Speech software
        //Perform any actions necessary
        Toast.makeText(context,
                "BEEP!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

And here's where I create the alarm notifications with AlarmManager

```
            if (!alarmExists(alarm)) {
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, alarm.getId(), intent, 0);
                if (alarm.isDaily() || alarm.isWeekly()) {
                    dbHandler.createAlarm(alarm);
                    Alarms.add(alarm);
                    alarmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if (alarm.isDaily())
                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmOrganizerTools.getAlarmTime(alarm), TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1), pendingIntent);
                    else if (alarm.isWeekly())
                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmOrganizerTools.getAlarmTime(alarm), TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(7), pendingIntent);

                    updateNextAlarm();
                }
                else {
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmOrganizerTools.getAlarmTime(alarm), pendingIntent);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Your Alarm has been created!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                resetAlarmCreator();

                updateNextAlarm();
            }
```

My issue is when the Alarm goes off and onReceive is called, I don't know how to associate that Alarm with one of my Alarm objects so that I could pull information from it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the ENTIRE alarm object for SOME information...

long answer short: put and get extra

```
if (!alarmExists(alarm)) 
{
    intent.putExtra("someKey", "some information here");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, alarm.getId(), intent, 0);
    if (alarm.isDaily() || alarm.isWeekly()) {
        dbHandler.createAlarm(alarm);
        Alarms.add(alarm);
        // rest of code here....
```

later on.. when dealing with onReceive

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent){
    String tada = intent.getStringExtra("someKey");
    // do something with that information
    Toast.makeText(context,
            "BEEP!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```